# Replace newlines in

Tags: linux, sed, awk

i have some xml files in linux

```
a="xx
xx
xx"
b="y
y
y"
```

How to replace the content and becomes

```
a="xx\n\xx\nxx"
b="y
y
y"
```

where attribute b is not replace

i have try this but how to support multi files and replace the attribute "a" only using sed or awk command; (not use xslt)

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' abc.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gawk

```
gawk -vRS="\nb=" '/a=/{ gsub("\n","\\n") }
{ if (RT == "") printf "%s", $0
  else print
}' ORS="\nb=" file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
a="xx\nxx\nxx"
b="y
y
y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` command that should work:

```
sed -n '/^a/ {:b; $b; N; /^a.*\"$/ {s/\n/\\n/gp;b};bb}; /^a/! p'
```