# replace newlines within quoted string with \n

Tags: regex, linux, perl, scripting, awk

I need to write a quick (by tomorrow) filter script to replace line breaks (LF or CRLF) found within double quoted strings by the escaped newline `\n`. The content is a (broken) javascript program, so I need to allow for escape sequences like `"ab\"cd"` and `"ab\\"cd"ef"` within a string.

I understand that sed is not well-suited for the job as it work per line, so I turn to perl, of which I know nothing :)

I've written this regex: `"(((\\.)|[^"\\\n])*\n?)*"` and tested it with the http://regex.powertoy.org. It indeed matches quoted strings with line breaks, however, `perl -p -e 's/"(((\\.)|[^"\\\n])*(\n)?)*"/TEST/g'` does not.

So my questions are:

1. how to make perl to match line breaks?
2. how to write the "replace-by" part so that it keeps the original string and only replaces newlines?

There is this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047740/replace-newlines-in) with awk solution, but it is not quite what I need.

NOTE: I usually don't ask "please do this for me" questions, but I really don't feel like learning perl/awk by tomorrow... :)

**EDIT**: sample data

```
"abc\"def" - matches as one string
"abc\\"def"xy" - match "abcd\\" and "xy"
"ab
cd
ef" - is replaced by "ab\ncd\nef"
```

Comment: Double quoted strings in what context?

Comment: well, javascript, but I don't think it's relevant. I don't need full parsing, just to recognize string literals

Comment: "Handling" `\"` and `\\"` could mean that you are expecting the string to get expanded twice. Or that you want to preserve a backslash that just happens to be placed before the closing `"`. Since you do not provide any desired output besides "handle correctly", I am left guessing what "correctly" means to you.

Comment: @davka, can you please post come example content to try? thanks

Comment: @TLP, @Joel, I see, will edit

Comment: @davka From what I can see from your examples, `\"` and `\\"` are already handled correctly. How do you want them handled differently?

Comment: @davka I see what you mean now. It's what you have been saying all along. You only want to do replacements inside quotes, and no where else. And that's why we have to take escaped quotation marks into consideration.

Comment: @TLP: I see the confusion. I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Perl solution:

```
s§
    \G # match from the beginning of the string or the last match
    ([^"]*+) # till we get to a quote
    "((?:[^"\\]++|\\.)*+)" # match the whole quote
§
    $a = $1;
    $b = $2;
    $b =~ s/\r?\n/\\n/g; # replace what you want inside the quote
    "$a\"$b\"";
§gex;
```

---

Here is another solution in case you wouldn't want to use `/e` and just do it with one regex:

```
use strict;

$_=<<'_quote_';
hai xtest "aa xx aax" baix "xx"
x "axa\"x\\" xa "x\\\\\"x" ax
xbai!x
_quote_

print "Original:\n", $_, "\n";

s/
(
    (?:
        # at the beginning of the string match till inside the quotes
        ^(?&outside_quote) "
        # or continue from last match which always stops inside quotes
        | (?!^)\G
    )
    (?&inside_quote)  # eat things up till we find what we want
)
x   # the thing we want to replace
(
    (?&inside_quote)  # eat more possibly till end of quote
    # if going out of quote make sure the match stops inside them
    # or at the end of string
    (?: " (?&outside_quote) (?:"|\z) )?
)

(?(DEFINE)
    (?<outside_quote> [^"]*+ ) # just eat everything till quoting starts
    (?<inside_quote> (?:[^"\\x]++|\\.)*+ ) # handle escapes
)
/$1Y$2/xg;

print "Replaced:\n", $_, "\n";
```

Output:

```
Original:
hai xtest "aa xx aax" baix "xx"
x "axa\"x\\" xa "x\\\\\"x" ax
xbai!x

Replaced:
hai xtest "aa YY aaY" baix "YY"
x "aYa\"Y\\" xa "Y\\\\\"Y" ax
xbai!x
```

To work with line breaks instead of x, just replace it in the regex like so:

```
s/
(
    (?:
        # at the beginning of the string match till inside the quotes
        ^(?&outside_quote) "
        # or continue from last match which always stops inside quotes
        | (?!^)\G
    )
    (?&inside_quote)  # eat things up till we find what we want
)
\r?\n # the thing we want to replace
(
    (?&inside_quote)  # eat more possibly till end of quote
    # if going out of quote make sure the match stops inside them
    # or at the end of string
    (?: " (?&outside_quote) (?:"|\z) )?
)

(?(DEFINE)
    (?<outside_quote> [^"]*+ ) # just eat everything till quoting starts
    (?<inside_quote> (?:[^"\\\r\n]++|\\.)*+ ) # handle escapes
)
/$1\\n$2/xg;
```

Comment: Remember to `use utf8;` if you're going to be using `§` in your code as a regex delimiter!

Comment: thanks. I get the following error with your first solution: `Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/`, `    ([^"]*+ <-- HERE ) # till we get to a quote`

Comment: @bdonlan, `§` is latin1, so no need to use utf8 (unless that's how you encode your file i guess).

Comment: @davka, update your perl, the one you are using must be ancient. Or you could remove all `+` which follow quantifiers (eg `+`, `*`).

Comment: what makes you think my (or the OP's) default editor charset setting would use latin1? :) You can find a non-unicode charset containing pretty much any character, but it's not a good idea to assume people are using it, particularly when most distros use utf8 by default these days.

Answer (score 1):

Until the OP posts some example content to test by, try adding the "m" (and possibly the "s") flag to the end of your regex; from [`perldoc perlreref` (reference)](http://p3rl.org/reref):

```
m  Multiline mode - ^ and $ match internal lines
s  match as a Single line - . matches \n
```

For testing you might also find that adding the command line argument "-i.bak" so that you keep a backup of the original file (now with the extension ".bak").

Note also that if you want to capture but not store something you can use `(?:PATTERN)` rather than `(PATTERN)`. Once you have your captured content use `$1` through `$9` to access stored matches from the matching section.

For more info see the link about as well as [`perldoc perlretut` (tutorial)](http://p3rl.org/retut) and [`perldoc perlre` (full-ish documentation)](http://p3rl.org/re)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Regexp::Common;

$_ = '"abc\"def"' . '"abc\\\\"def"xy"' . qq("ab\ncd\nef");

print "befor: {{$_}}\n";
s{($RE{quoted})}
 {  (my $x=$1) =~ s/\n/\\n/g;
    $x
 }ge;
print "after: {{$_}}\n";
```

Comment: `Can't locate Regexp/Common.pm` - I guess it is an add-on?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl 5.14.0 (install with [perlbrew](http://p3rl.org/App%3a%3aperlbrew)) one can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.14.0;

use Regexp::Common qw/delimited/;

my $data = <<'END';
"abc\"def"
"abc\\"def"xy"
"ab
cd
ef"
END

my $output = $data =~ s/$RE{delimited}{-delim=>'"'}{-keep}/$1=~s!\n!\\n!rg/egr;

print $output;
```

I need 5.14.0 for the `/r` flag of the internal replace. If someone knows how to avoid this please let me know.

Comment: %$^#, while I was working on this BOTH tadmc and Qtax got there before me!